# Form in custom controller with Turbolinks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Using Rails 6. Here's my code:

```
# search_controller.rb
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
  end
end

# search/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with url: search_index_path, method: :get do |form| %>
  <%= form.search_field :q %>
  <%= form.button class: "btn py-0 px-2" do %>
    <i class="f7-icons">search</i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  get 'search/index'
  ...
end

# blogs/index.html.erb
<%= render "search/form" %>

# output of /blogs
<form action="/search/index" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="get">
  <input type="search" name="q" id="q">
  <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn py-0 px-2">
    <i class="f7-icons">search</i>
  </button>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, it doesn't route to `search/index.html.erb`. Here's the log:

```
Started GET "/search/index?q=iron&button=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-12-27 21:54:40 +0800
Processing by SearchController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"q"=>"iron", "button"=>""}
  Rendering search/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered search/_form.html.erb (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 815)
  Rendered search/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.9ms | Allocations: 1116)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 15.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2731)
```

When I add the `local: true` to the `form_with` in `search/_form.html.erb`, the page renders properly. Here's the log:

```
Started GET "/search/index?q=iron&button=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-12-27 21:58:09 +0800
Processing by SearchController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"q"=>"iron", "button"=>""}
  Rendering search/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered search/_form.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 808)
  Rendered search/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 952)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2511)
```

I understand that Turblinks is in play with the `data-remote: true`. Here is my question:

If I use `local: true` which removes the `data-remote: true`, it also removes the Turbolink partial page rendering, which is a full page reload. How can I use `data-remote: true` still, and get Turbolink to work out of the box, just like normal CRUD, without creating this:

```
# index.js.erb
Turbolinks.visit("<%= search_index_path %>");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Turbolinks only handles links - not forms. ‘local: true’ disables the Rails ujs form handler. Which creates a request for JavaScript instead of html by default. Making this the default behavior is probably the stupidest thing that has happened in Rails.

Comment: In previous versions you would opt in to the js.erb  nonsense in by using 'remote: true'.